# Serving Static files separately on S3 for next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-s3, kubernetes, next.js

I am trying to deploy next.JS on Kubernetes. But I also want all the static files to get served from s3. Is there any way to do that?

For Example. Currently, all the static files are being served from the local file system of the server.

```
<link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/chunks/main.js?ts=1616564196729" as="script">
<link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1616564196729" as="script">
<link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js?ts=1616564196729" as="script">
<link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/chunks/pages/index.js?ts=1616564196729" as="script">
.
.
.
<script src="/_next/static/chunks/main.js?ts=1616564196729"></script>
```

But instead I want them to get served from S3 like below:

```
<link rel="preload" href="SOME_S3_URL/static/chunks/main.js?ts=1616564196729" as="script">
<link rel="preload" href="SOME_S3_URLt/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1616564196729" as="script">
<link rel="preload" href="SOME_S3_URL/static/chunks/pages/_app.js?ts=1616564196729" as="script">
<link rel="preload" href="SOME_S3_URL/static/chunks/pages/index.js?ts=1616564196729" as="script">
.
.
.
<script src="SOME_S3_URL/_next/static/chunks/main.js?ts=1616564196729"></script>
```